# One-to-One Function from N to odd digits

Tags: functions

I'm trying to get One-to-One Function from N to the group (partial to N) where there are only numbers with odd digits.

i.e. :

$f(1234) = 13$ [Just for example. This idea is not good, because the function is not One-to-One].

Any direction / help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion 1:

Map each digit to two digits:

0 --> 11
1 --> 13
2 --> 15
3 --> 17
4 --> 19
5 --> 31
6 --> 33
7 --> 35
8 --> 37
9 --> 39

Suggestion 2:
Map n to a number consisting of n ones:
1 --> 1
2 --> 11
13 --> 1111111111111

Suggestion 3:
Using the odd digits we could express the original number in base 5 and then map each digit 0-4 to 1-9.

Example: 
28 in base 5 is 103 which would map to 317.

Note that all three suggestions are injective but none is bijective. One might think that 3 is bijective but it is not unless you infer the special characteristics of zero to 1.

Using suggestion 3, the inverse of 317, 1317 and 11317 would all be 28 just like 28, 028 and 0028 all map to 317.

Comment: Hmm. One-to-One function is required. Suggestions 1 and 2 will never produce the number 7, for example. So, what would be $f^{-1}(7)$?
Suggestion 3 looks ok.

Comment: $7$ doesn't have to be in the co-domain of $f$.

Comment: Added a note on injectivity/bijectivity, especially for suggestion 3.